# Displaying WordPress posts without featured image using shortcode

Tags: wordpress

So our former developer crafted a code and put it in the functions.php file to be able to use these shortcodes: [display_page_thumbnail] [display_posts_thumbnail]

This makes it easier for us to track all our posts/pages without featured images. Here's how it looks in the front end: https://prnt.sc/pxqHavKgpyXJ

However, we tried copying the code over to another site, but the shortcodes don't work: https://prnt.sc/rV5p7zSCICFP

I'm thinking maybe our functions.php file is messed up that's why the shortcodes don't work? This is the contents of our functions.php files:

In our old site that the shortcodes work: https://www.toptal.com/developers/paste-gd/zPSkNBEV
In our new site that the shortcodes don't work: https://www.toptal.com/developers/paste-gd/I4j68fWl

Anyone can please help?

Comment: Are both sites using the same theme? Are you entering the shortcodes in the main content area, or some other field?

Comment: @Caleb yes both are using the Avada theme and shortcodes are inserted using the Code Block. Maybe there is a problem in the functions.php files? Like the curly brackets, etc?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `functions.php` is being loaded?

Comment: @Caleb how do I confirm this sir?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I got it to work. Turns out, as stupid as it is, the child theme wasn't activated lol. Thanks so much sir!!